# Angular 2 tree shaking with webpack 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, webpack-2

I'm trying to reduce the size of my angular 2 application by applying tree shaking technique.

I'm using `webpack 2.1.0-beta.22`, `angular 2 rc6` and `typescript 2.0.2`.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

webpack.config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
        }
    ]
},
plugins: {
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        debug: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        beautify: false,
        compress: { screw_ie8: true },
        comments: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        sourceMap: true
    })
}
```

Bundle size before tree shaking was ~ 1.7MB, and after tree shaking size became ~ 1.8MB.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I guess you need to use rollup. Please check this article http://blog.rangle.io/optimize-your-angular2-application-with-tree-shaking/ that says, "the UglifyJs plugin used in the Webpack build is not able to remove unused Typescript classes...To be able to properly apply tree shaking we need to use a different module loader like Rollup." and the official doc https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#tree-shaking